# Background service in new Android versions

Tags: android, background-service

I have an application with background service (important tasks run in background always).
What is your offer for handle important tasks?
my application may be close but these tasks must be done.

Comment: by using foreground service

Comment: post your code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your service is doing important task and the application mustn't be close you should use [`Foreground Service`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground) as it will inform the user that you're doing some work.

If you don't need immediate execution you can use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics). WorkManager offers **deferrable** but **guaranteed** execution, it'll run even if you're application is killed.